# Studying medicine in Germany

Tags: university, germany, international-students, medicine, abroad

I'm a medical student from Alexandria, Egypt. By next year I'll have completed the pre-clinical phase of the program and I'm wondering if I can study the clinical phase in Germany (Germany has the same program arrangement)

Is there a test that l can take to study the clinical phase directly without having to start all over ?

Answer (score 1):

German universities have a process to determine whether exams etc passed at a different institution shall be deemed equivalent to a degree component there. This is handled by the individual departments, the keyword is "anrechnen". When moving between similar degrees inside Germany, this will usually be straight-forward.

When you are asking for courses from Egypt to be counted, you'd probably need to provide a very detailed syllabus and maybe additional sources to make the case that they indeed cover everything important the German course would have. To get a clear decision, you would probably need to at least apply, maybe even enrol at the German university.

When studying medicine in Germany, the step from pre-clinical studies to clinical studies is when students take the first component of the Staatsexamen. I expect that it would be much easier to get the individual pre-clinical courses deemed equivalent, and thus get authorized to sit the first component of the Staatsexamen, than it would be to get any foreign exam counted as the first component of the Staatsexamen itself.